# Listing files in directory in one column

Tags: command-line, ls

Is there a command to print the files in a directory in a single column without this additional info? Basically an `ls` command but with the output format of:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

as opposed to :

```
file1.txt file2.txt 
file3.txt
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need the `ls` command `-1` option.

```
ls -1 /dir
```

just to clarify. that is `ls -(one) /dir`; like the number.

from the [man ls](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ls.1.html) page:

```
 -1     list one file per line.  Avoid '\n' with -q or -b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`. To list only files in the current dir, you can use `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`.

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./file3.txt
```